# Why can't I schedule more pods even with Ipv4Prefix enabled in my EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-eks, cilium

I am using cilium as my CNI. I have successfully run the `cilium connectivity test` and all tests pass. My nodegroup schedules a `t3.small` nodes (3 of them), which allows me to run 11 pods without `Ipv4Prefix` enabled. Now I have enabled `Ipv4Prefix` by running

```
kubectl set env daemonset aws-node -n kube-system ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION=true
```

and when I run:

```
kubectl describe daemonset -n kube-system aws-node | grep ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION
```

I get :

```
  ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION:  true
  ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION:  true
  ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION:  true
```

I have also installed cilium by running the following:

```
helm install cilium cilium/cilium --version 1.15.0 --namespace kube-system --set eni.enabled=true --set ipam.mode=eni --set eni.awsEnablePrefixDelegation=true --set egressMasqueradeInterfaces=eth0
```

and patched the daemonset like so:

```
kubectl -n kube-system patch daemonset aws-node --type='strategic' -p='{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"nodeSelector":{"io.cilium/aws-node-enabled":"true"}}}}}'
```

I can see all the pods are running fine.

[image]

I can also see that prefix has been assigned to the eni:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region eu-west-2 --network-interface-ids eni-0eb1aff34572830d6 | grep Ipv4Prefix
    "Ipv4Prefixes": [
                "Ipv4Prefix": "10.0.1.112/28"
                "Ipv4Prefix": "10.0.1.224/28"
```

QUESTION

I know the `t3.small` instances can have a max pod of 110, however, I still cannot schedule more than 11 pods per instance. What could be the issue?

**ERROR**

```
 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Too many pods. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

this should not be the case when IPV4 prefix is enabled

Comment: What does it mean you cannot schedule? What are the errors you are getting? Did you check with `kubectl top node` if you have sufficient resources available?

Comment: no nodes available to have another pod @user23204747